# TextAlignment vs ContentHorizontalAlignment

Tags: c#, wpf

What's the difference between **`TextAlignment`** & **`ContentHorizontalAlignment`**?

I tried using both with a TextBox but they always achieve the same result when I remove the other

Comment: It's the same result for you current (likely very simple) layout, but when layout become more complex you will quickly see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that TextAlignment semantically applies downward to child text, whereas HorizontalContentAlignment applies downward not only to child text but also child controls.

[TextAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.textalignment?view=netframework-4.8) is an enum with the values:

- Center = 2 = Text is centered
- Justify = 3 = Text is justified
- Left = 0 = Default. Text aligned to the left
- Right = 1 = Text is aligned to the right.

[HorizontalContentAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment?view=netframework-4.8) is a property of the Control class of type HorizontalAlignment.

[HorizontalAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.horizontalalignment?view=netframework-4.8) is an enum with the following values:

- Center = 1 = An element aligned to the center of the layout slot for the parent element.
- Left = 0 = An element aligned to the left of the layout slot for the parent element.
- Right = 2 = An element aligned to the right of the layout slot for the parent element.
- Stretch = 3 = An element stretched to fill the entire layout slot of the parent element.